# Full Calendar events offset by 1 calendar interval

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar

Using full calendar to display events, although the events are all 30 minutes later than they should be:
[image]

The data that full calendar is getting from the server:

```
[{"title":"student123","start":"2016-10-05 10:00:00","id":"18","end":"2016-10-05 11:00:00"},
{"title":"student123","start":"2016-10-05 02:00:00","id":"19","end":"2016-10-05 03:00:00"},
{"title":"student123","start":"2016-10-05 14:00:00","id":"20","end":"2016-10-05 15:00:00"},
{"title":"student123","start":"2016-10-06 12:00:00","id":"21","end":"2016-10-06 13:00:00"}]
```

Any idea why they would be shown all 30 minutes later? I can click on an open space and it comes up with the right time. There are no timezones being used at all.

EDIT:  After some more investigation it seems like the events are just pushed down one slot. If I change the intervals to 15 minutes each, the events are now only 15 pushed ahead.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that replicates the issue?

Comment: Will see what i can come up with.

Comment: Started making a fiddle and everything was working fine. It turns out that the default CSS file that Phoenix gives you is messing up the events.

Comment: Glad you found the culprit. I'll vote to close the question as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error".

Comment: Works for me, thanks for the idea of creating a fiddle, need to do that more often